# Gos web socket bundle is not working with `symfony 4.2`

Tags: php, symfony, socket.io, web-notifications

I am trying to implement a notification system similar to Facebook in Symfony 4.2. I tried installing `gos/web-socket-bundle` with composer. But it always return an error with `error code 1`. Is there any other alternate solution to implement this or suggest the method to fix this issue.
https://packagist.org/packages/gos/web-socket-bundle
`In GosWebSocketExtension.php line 206: Shared configuration required Twig Bundle`

`Script cache:clear returned with error code 1`

I tried installing with the following command
`composer require gos/web-socket-bundle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do Ratchet + Symfony Combination.

Ratchet is the best solution, I recommend. (http://socketo.me/docs/install)

Answer (score 0):

You need install two requires to fix it:

```
composer require symfony/tiwg-bundle 
composer require symfony/security-bundle
```